# Why Find method get out of range MongDb C# driver 2.10.4?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi i try to duplicate my collection in the database. I have white the following `Main`:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MongoCRUD db = new MongoCRUD("testClass");


        /* copy the colection*/
        var targetTable = "geo2";
        var newTable = "NormalizeCordinatesGeo";

        db.CopyColection<GlobalUrbanPoint>(targetTable, newTable);
    }
```

The following class is for my model

```
public class GlobalUrbanPoint 
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId  Id{ get; set; }
        public double LATITUDE { get; set; } 
        public double LONGITUDE { get; set; } 
        ...
    }
```

For the the operation in my program i use use `MongoCRUD` class:

```
        public class MongoCRUD
    {
        private IMongoDatabase db;

        public MongoCRUD(string database)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient();
            db = client.GetDatabase(database);
        }

        ...

        public void CopyColection<T>(string targetTable, string newTable)
        {
            var source_colection = db.GetCollection<T>(targetTable);
            var dest = db.GetCollection<T>(newTable);
            dest.InsertMany(source_colection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList());

        }

    }
```

To test the function `CopyColection` i have crate a colocation with 6 documents and it work as expected.
When i try to copy a larger collection more specific with 66.579 documents i get flowing error

`System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the TYPE property of class MongoDBCurve.Program+GlobalUrbanPoint: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

I do not understand do i need to specify the bounds? I need to create a batches because the collection is to large ?

Can someone explain to my why this occurs and what i need to do to copy properly my collection.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake that i made after try and error. The types of filed of my class it was different from the data in database.